# Kafka consumer does not read messages from the queue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

There are 2 services with reading from the the same topic, the configurations are the same except for groupId, 1 partition, in the logs I see the same consumer configuration and successful connection. One service reads messages from the queue, the other does not. Of the differences found, there are logs in the working service:

```
Setting offset for partition topic-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=420, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch
```

And in the second service there are no such. Tried different auto.offset.reset, doesn't help. The implementation of working with kafka in services is identical. What could be the problem?

Comment: You need to show your code and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Do both services read from the same topic?

If the topic has only 1 partition, then only 1 consumer will receive messages.
If you want to distribute messages across multiple consumers, then you'd have to specify more than 1 partition (more than number of consumers).

However, if you want *all* consumers to receive *all* messages, then you'd have to specify different `consumer group id` for each consumer (which in your case is: each service).

Comment: i want all consumers to receive all messages, i have specified different consumer group id for each consumer, it did not help

Comment: Double check if you configured them correctly. You can also use Kafka Manager to check which consumers are connected and verify if consumer group id displayed in there is matching what you have configured.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the @Builder annotation for the domain class of the message, after replacing it with @SuperBuilder, everything began to work as it should. It's weird, I didn't have inheritance from this class.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).